# Using count() in a sub query vs outside of sub query

Tags: sql, count, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to learn the significance of counting a variable inside of a subquery vs outside.
Query1: using count() inside, getting wrong results, but I don't know why:

```
sel
monthday_key,
 mfr_mdl_code,
--svc_time_Zone_Code,
cntc_rqst_subarea_desc, 
CALL_COUNT
from 
(
sel 
monthday_key,
--svc_time_Zone_Code,
mfr_mdl_code, 
 cntc_rqst_subarea_desc 
 ,mfr_Ser_id, 
 count(cntc_rqst_id) call_count
from cust_Acct_equip_fact A join monthday_dim b on monthday_key between bgn_monthday_key and end_monthday_key 
and equip_stat_code = 'ACTV' and monthday_key = current_Date-1
join equip_type_dim C on a.equip_type_key=c.equip_type_key and mfr_mdl_code like any ('C21)
join cntc_rqst_tech_fact D on a.cust_acct_key=cntc_key and cntc_Rqst_bgn_Date = monthday_key and cntc_rqst_bgn_date = current_Date-1
join cust_acct_dim E on a.cust_acct_key=e.cust_Acct_key
AND D.CNTC_RQST_SUBAREA_DESC in ('NO SS')
--and svc_time_Zone_Code in ('P','E','M','C')
group by 1,2,3,4
) T1 
group by 1,2,3,4
```

Using Count() outside sub-query, getting right results:

```
sel
monthday_key,
 mfr_mdl_code,
--svc_time_Zone_Code,
cntc_rqst_subarea_desc, 
count(cntc_Rqst_id) as CALL_COUNT
from 
(
sel 
monthday_key,
--svc_time_Zone_Code,
mfr_mdl_code, 
 cntc_rqst_subarea_desc 
 ,mfr_Ser_id, 
 cntc_rqst_id
from cust_Acct_equip_fact A join monthday_dim b on monthday_key between bgn_monthday_key and end_monthday_key 
and equip_stat_code = 'ACTV' and monthday_key = current_Date-1
join equip_type_dim C on a.equip_type_key=c.equip_type_key and mfr_mdl_code like any ('C21')
join cntc_rqst_tech_fact D on a.cust_acct_key=cntc_key and cntc_Rqst_bgn_Date = monthday_key and cntc_rqst_bgn_date = current_date-1
join cust_acct_dim E on a.cust_acct_key=e.cust_Acct_key
AND D.CNTC_RQST_SUBAREA_DESC in ('NO SS')
--and svc_time_Zone_Code in ('P','E','M','C')
group by 1,2,3,4,5
) T1 
group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: You got multiple rows with the same `monthday_key,
mfr_mdl_code, 
 cntc_rqst_subarea_desc 
 ,mfr_Ser_id,cntc_rqst_id` combination, Q2 applies DISTNCT and removes duplicates. Changing Q1 to `count(DISTINCT cntc_rqst_id)` should return the same result (and there's no need for the subquery/Derived Table, of course).

Comment: I actually figured it out yesterday too. The reason I'm getting wrong results is because I'm counting at a "id" level in the subquery vs the outside it's proper aggregate just for the date. But I appreciate your response.